# Getting 'href' value of an anchor inside another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Suppose I have this:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="someplace">some text</a><li>
...
</ul>
```

I want to make every `li` clickable so I need to extract the value of `href` like this:

```
$('#menu li').click(function() {
    var link_to = $(SELECTOR THAT I NEED).attr('href');
    window.location = link_to;
});
```

what's the correct code for this? Is there a better way?

Comment: why do have to bind the click on li?.. why not make the anchor do what it does? change the css of the anchor to height:100% and width:100%

Comment: Because I had not thought of that :) See my comment on the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a link in there, why not use that ?

you could set it to `display:block` with `css` if you want it to take up the whole `li` width ..

```
#menu li a{display:block;}
```

and avoid using jquery for built in functionality .. (*if i understand correctly..*)

Comment: Good point, haven't thought of `display: block`. It's not ideal though because the padding of the `li` elements is outside the `a` block and so is "dead".

Comment: Yes you are right .. but it was worth a shot without knowing exactly what you are after :) The asnwers above should do it then ..

Comment: i'll vote this one up and remove my own post. it is clearly redundant to have a lot of click bindings when the anchor semantically handles onclicks. i'd say it's definitely worth the css-effort to remove the padding that the li's create.

Comment: I agree, accepting this as it answers the "is there a better way" part of my question. The other answers were good too, yours David was the most concise version

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#menu li').click(function() {
    var link_to = $(this).children("a").eq(0).attr('href');
    window.location = link_to;
});
```

Comment: I'd personally prefer `$(this).children("a:first").attr("href")`

Comment: `$('a:first', this)` would be a neat way to avoid having to run the clicked `li` through the `$` function. providing context in this manner is exactly the same as `find`. i've already cast my vote for the don't-do-what-you're-trying-to-do alternative, but i think this post, and its comments, is a valid documentation for those who stumble upon this question, having a *similar* question of their own, where Gaby's reply is not applicable =)